# I can not find any optional parameters to pass the RTC workitem number on command line

Tags: maven-scm

**Error code as below:**

[ERROR] 'Deliver' failed. Preconditions have not been met: A work item must be associated with the change set.
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project junit-ext: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
Error code for Jazz SCM deliver command - 17

Tried with following command

mvn --batch-mode -B -Dresume=false release:prepare -X

Is there any way to forcefully do the deliver without any workitem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Workarround for this problem:

In RTC we can configure the workitem or message condition.
Once doing the workitem optional parameter, you can eassily deliver the code using below command

**mvn --batch-mode -B -Dresume=false release:prepare -X**